# Skip Null Values in XML to JSON without skipping nillable elements

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule4

I have an XML Input:

```
<XML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ABC xsi:nil="true"/>
</XML>
```

dataweave code:

```
%dw2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
{
  abc: payload.ABC,
  def: payload.DEF 
}
```

expected output:

```
{
  "abc": null
}
```

I want to skip the null values from XML, but don't want the nillable values i.e. elements that contain xsi:nil="true" to skip

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following dataweave construct to define what elements should be written in the output payload:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  (abc: payload.XML.ABC) if (payload.XML.ABC?) //abc will be written only if it exists in the payload (whether its value is nil or not)
  (def: payload.XML.DEF) if (payload.XML.DEF?) //def will be written only if it exists in the payload (whether its value is nil or not)
}
```

Example:
[image: dw do not output missing input elements]

Comment: In my case we cannot predict which XML element will have ' xsi:nil="true" ' we can write if condition only if we know which XML element is nillable. do we have any solution without using 'if', like some property like 'writeNilOnNull=true' etc.

Comment: Hey Amit, you can add the condition for every element you are mapping. That way, the element only will be written in the output if they exist in the input.

Comment: Yeah, possible solution, but I have almost 200+ elements, and it is not feasible to add a if condn for all.

Comment: Ok. Could you please update the question and add an excerpt of your actual mapping?

Answer (score 0):

A coma is missing in the DataWeave

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
  (abc: payload.XML.ABC) if (payload.XML.ABC?), //abc will be written only if it exists in the payload (whether its value is nil or not)
  (def: payload.XML.DEF) if (payload.XML.DEF?)  //def will be written only if it exists in the payload (whether its value is nil or not)
}
```